# How to transform the image from cloudinay cloud using Meteor react?

Tags: cloudinary, meteor-react

I am using this code:

```
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary';
    {cloudinary.Image(
            'http://res.cloudinary.com/dtkptr7rt/image/upload/v1512735944/kb4gvy7d4jskexkstcti.jpg'
          )}
```

Which raises this error:

> Cannot read property 'Image' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Cloudinary's React package and follow the instructions there - https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-react

Regardless, `cloudinary.Image` should be provided with a public Id (i.e., image Id) and not a URL.

Also, the URL is not accessible.

Comment: yeah i tried react-cloudinary component and it sorts the problem.